# Input: сдвиг введенного текста в начало при потере фокуса

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, css

При заполнении поля (input), если ввести слишком большой текст и "уйти" с поля, будет виден только хвост введенных данных. Как сделать так, чтобы при "уходе" с поля было видно начало данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setCaretPosition (ctrl, pos) {
  if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {//не ИЕ
    ctrl.focus();
    ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
  } else if (ctrl.createTextRange) { //ИЕ
    var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', pos);
    range.moveStart('character', pos);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

ctrl - объект input или textarea с которым работаем

pos - позиция куда ставим курсор

Единственное, для показа начала строки мы переводим курсор в начало (при этом делая фокус  на поле ввода). После этого понадобится вызвать потерю фокуса (мы же ушли с поля). Есть смысл навешивать эту функцию на поле с однократным вызовом.

Comment: Круто. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Для полноты картины, остается добавить:    // при фокусе - в самый конец строки    $('selector').focus(function(){        setCaretPosition(this,$(this).val().length);    });    // при потере фокуса - в самое начало    $('selector').blur(function(){        setCaretPosition(this,0);    });[http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tJMt2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tJMt2/)